# Stored procedure that contains a temporary table and a cursor doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I need to get an hierarchy of some projects in a temporary table because the project for which the hierarchy is made depends on a trigger after update. So I need to insert the result of a stored procedure in a temporary table. After that I need a cursor in order to loop throgh all the results and after that to make some updates. Here is my code..I dont't know why but it doesn't enter the loop, or that's what I think.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPDATE_UDF_VALUES_HIERARCHY] ( 
                @proj_id INT
                                                    ) 
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @tmpHierarchy TABLE ( 
                                    proj_id       INT , 
                                    parent_wbs_id INT
                                    );

        DECLARE @projid INT , @parent_wbs_id INT , @Total INT , @Totaltest INT;
        INSERT INTO @tmpHierarchy ( proj_id , parent_wbs_id
                                  ) 
        EXEC GetHierarchyForProject @proj_id;

        --INSERT INTO @tmpHierarchy
        --Exec GetHierarchyForProject @proj_id
        -- to break the match in all scanora

        UPDATE udfvalue
               SET udf_number = ( SELECT SUM(udf_number)
                                  FROM UDFVALUE
                                  WHERE udf_type_id = 1
                                        AND 
                                        proj_id = @proj_id
                                )
        WHERE udf_type_id = 2
              AND 
              proj_id = @proj_id;

        DECLARE db_cursor_hierarchy_andreea CURSOR

        FOR SELECT *
            FROM @tmpHierarchy;

        OPEN db_cursor_hierarchy_andreea;

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_hierarchy_andreea INTO @projid , @parent_wbs_id;

        IF @proj_id != @projid
            BEGIN
                IF EXISTS ( SELECT proj_id
                            FROM udfvalue
                            WHERE proj_id = @projid
                                  AND 
                                  udf_type_id = 2
                          ) 
                    BEGIN
                        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @Totaltest = SUM(udf_number)
                                FROM udfvalue
                                WHERE udf_type_id = 2
                                      AND 
                                      fk_id IN ( SELECT proj_id
                                                 FROM PROJWBS
                                                 WHERE parent_wbs_id = ( SELECT wbs_id
                                                                         FROM projwbs
                                                                         WHERE proj_id = @projid
                                                                       )
                                               );
                                UPDATE udfvalue
                                       SET udf_number = @Totaltest
                                WHERE udf_type_id = 2
                                      AND 
                                      proj_id = @projid;
                            END;
                    END;
                FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_hierarchy_andreea INTO @projid , @parent_wbs_id;

        END;
        CLOSE db_cursor_hierarchy_andreea;
        DEALLOCATE db_cursor_hierarchy_andreea;
    END;
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop in the first place? This whole looping construct and such could be replaced with a single update statement.

Comment: As for debugging your current code, add some print statements inside your nested IF statements. My guess is one or both of those conditions is false.

Comment: result of EXEC GetHierarchyForProject @proj_id  is a table that contains a hierarchy for some given project..and the update that I have to do deffers on some value of the project. Maybe is something I miss.

Comment: Everything seems ok ?

Comment: Right I can see your procedure gets some rows. But that doesn't mean you have to use a cursor to update one at a time.

Comment: seems your `IF` statements have to be inside your loop

Comment: I don;t need? Are you sure? I can add an update and it will do it for all the rows of the temp table..it doesn;t really make sense

Comment: I would not use any if statements or a loop here at all. Get your results into a temp table and then do a single update statement with a join.

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin should I place them elsewhere ?

Comment: @Sean Lange join with what ? :) with my temp table ?

Comment: YES!!! I am really struggling to unravel this code there are so many subselects going on.

Comment: I'm really lost..I dont understand wht can I change..

Comment: I think what would really help is a lot of details about your tables. At this point we are guessing. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @Mircea what do you see that makes you think the code doesn't enter the loop?   If you don't get an error, exactly what is it about the results that make you think the code isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your `@projid` is not initialized and so it is `null`.  So, when you execute `if @proj_id!=@projid` is always returns a false so you never enter the loop.

Before the `if` make sure to do something like `SET @projid = -1`.

Comment: Did you miss this line?   `FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_hierarchy_andreea INTO @projid,@parent_wbs_id`

Comment: I did miss the line, but @projid may still be null if there aren't any records.

Comment: That's true, it would be a good idea to check `@@FETCH_STATUS` before checking the value of `@projid`.